# Is there a good object mapper for Amazons dynamodb(through aws sdk) which can be used in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Maybe the question does not apply to dynamoDB due to it not being Relational Db. 
However, I'm looking for a good object mapper which can be used in nodejs and aws sdk to map existing model classes to dynamoDB tables. Does anyone have experience with this issue/question, or have you used such a module/library?

Answer (score 38):

If you are looking for schema:

- https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels (well supported [forked from *vogels* which has been abandoned](https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels/issues/171))
- https://github.com/automategreen/dynamoose (inspired by [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/))

If you are looking for something to throw javascript objects (even circular graphs) to:

- https://github.com/aaaristo/dyngodb (alpha)
- https://github.com/aaaristo/angular-gson-express-dyngodb

dyngodb has experimental support for full-text search, and [transactions](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions/blob/master/DESIGN.md) too.

Both are based on aws-sdk.

Answer (score 7):

Also worth considering is simple marshallers, which just translate between the dynamoDB format and regular js objects or JSON.

**DynamoDb-Data-Types**
https://github.com/kayomarz/dynamodb-data-types
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-data-types

"This utility helps represent AWS DynamoDb data types. It maps (marshalls) JavaScript data into the format required by DynamoDb."

**dynamoDb-marshaler**
https://github.com/CascadeEnergy/dynamoDb-marshaler
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-marshaler

"Translates sane javascript objects (and JSON) into DynamoDb format and vice versa."  [does not support B type.]

**Update 2016-06**:
Just discovered that the AWS SDK now does this for you.  Their documentation is only partially converted so I guess this is a recent addition.  Read about [it here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html).

But these marshallers are still useful because there are circumstances where you can't use the new document client, eg. when processing a dynamoDB stream.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I am using dynamoDB streams and currently they have to be transformed to javascript or JSON objects when they trigger my Lambda functions.

Comment: Thanks for *Update 2016-06*, it really nice!

Answer (score 7):

You could also try: https://dynamoosejs.com/. It is inspired by mongoose again.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Typescript, [dynamo-easy](https://github.com/shiftcode/dynamo-easy) might be a good option. Just add some decorators to your model and start using it.

```
import { Model, PartitionKey, DynamoStore } from '@shiftcoders/dynamo-easy'

@Model()
export class Person {
  @PartitionKey()
  id: string
  name: string
  yearOfBirth: number
}

const personStore = new DynamoStore(Person)

personStore
  .scan()
  .whereAttribute('yearOfBirth').equals(1958)
  .exec()
  .then(res => console.log('ALL items with yearOfBirth == 1958', res))
```

It uses the AWS DynamoDB sdk but takes care of the mapping between JS and DynamoDB types and provides a simple to use fluent API.

*full disclosure: I am one of the authors of this library*

Answer (score 1):

After looking over all the posts I landed on https://github.com/awspilot/dynamodb-oop

It doesn't hide the API but instead just wraps it in a nice, fluent way with promises even and you inject your version of the aws-sdk. It's similar to dynamodb-data-types but also wraps the methods too (not just the data types).

Extra bonus, the same author has https://github.com/awspilot/dynamodb-sql Didn't use the sql wrapper but I can see how some people may prefer that.

Dynamoose is obviously inspired by mongoose and is a good choice if you have a well-defined schema and/or want to be abstracted away from the DynamoDB details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [dynasaur](https://github.com/tglines/dynasaur)?  It seems to be the type of thing you're looking for, but I have not used it myself.  There's also [dynamodb-data-types](https://github.com/kayomarz/dynamodb-data-types) which is not an ORM, but makes it easy to convert to/from standard JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you check out [Dynamode](https://github.com/blazejkustra/dynamode?tab=readme-ov-file), a DynamoDB client I created last year. It's designed to work flawlessly with Typescript. It integrates nicely with Node.js and AWS SDK, and it might be just what you're looking for. Give it a spin!