# Is there a good query builder for Amazon's DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I tracked down [this package](https://github.com/noppoMan/npdynamodb). Generally it's pretty nice. But it seems to lack support for [Projection Expressions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html). What is your tool of choice for dynamodb in node/typescript?

I'm not fan of the data mappers listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23793071/592641) because they tend to wrap the table data, or are abandoned as projects.

Comment: did you check https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamoose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use dynogels, it is maintained until to date.

https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels

Answer (score 2):

If typescript is an option, we use https://github.com/shiftcode/dynamo-easy. Which also does not support Projection Expression, but the underlying params can always be [accessed and manipulated](https://shiftcode.gitbook.io/dynamo-easy/api/dynamo-store/model-requests#request-params), so adding some non-supported feature is easy.

```
import { DynamoStore } from '@shiftcoders/dynamo-easy'

const queryRequest = new DynamoStore(PersonModel)
    .query()
    .wherePartitionKey('2018-01')
    .whereSortKey().beginsWith('a')
    .limit(1)

    const queryParams = queryRequest.params
    queryParams.ProjectionExpression = 'projectionExpression'
    // also add expression attribute names if required
    queryParams.ExpressionAttributeNames = {'#someExpressionAttributeName': 'someExpressionAttributeName'}

    // you can also use new DynamoDB().query(queryParams), but we just use the preconfigured wrapped client  
    queryRequest.dynamoDBWrapper.makeRequest('query', queryParams)
        .then(r => console.log('first found item with projection expression:', r))
```

*full disclosure: I am one of the authors of this library*

Answer (score 0):

If you need a GUI to construct your query, try using the "DynamoDB Visual Query Builder" I've built: https://dynobase.dev/dynamodb-query-builder/